# Escping quotes in PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, quotes

How can I find only the telephone number (1234827382) in the following string ($x)?

****IMPORTANT:** I used `htmlspecialchars()` function on `$x` (text). Without useing this function the regex works. I need to find a regex solution when I use `htmlspecialchars()` before regex.**

```
 font-size: 14px; color: #333;" >asd:</td> <td width="150" align="left" valign="top"
    bgcolor="#f5f5f5" style="padding: 6px; border: 1px solid
    #eaeaea;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color:
    #333;" >Tel:</td> <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px; color: #333;" ><a href="tel:1234827382">1234827382</a></td> </tr>
<tr> <td width="150" align="left"
```

I have tried:

```
$p = '/href="tel:12.{20}/';
preg_match_all($p, $x, $matchestel);
print_r($matchestel);
```

If I try escape with \ then it also dont work:

```
$p = '/href=\"tel:12.{20}/';
```

If the text doesnt contain quote: <a href=tel:1234827382" (instead of this: <a href="tel:1234827382" )
then it finds, and after that I could remove the href" from the beginning. I know it is not the best solution.
I think the problem is that I need to escape the " from pattern.

Comment: You don't have a capture group `()` : ex: `'/href="tel:([0-9]+)"/'` ([demo](https://3v4l.org/nZNaq)). But use an XML parser should be more accurate.

Comment: No, use `htmlspecialchars` after the regex replace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quote by using a backslash.

In your case `/href=\"tel:12.{20}/`

Edit: If you use `htmlspecialchars($x)`, the quote sign `"` becomes `&quot;`, so you need to update the regex to `/href=&quot;tel:12.{20}/`

Comment: thats what I tried first, but didnt worked

Comment: See the output at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bb1b4850dafdefef7611f3d6165358505e2b3b46 ... It returns the substring here, so my guess is that the issue is in some other part of your code.

Comment: yes, your code works fine. I forgot to mention that I used htmlspecialchars on $x.
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aa358213c39db3fb567ccf7ff458da2f07418f54

Comment: @John That's important information. Ok, updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if your case is that numbers are not having any especial characters you can use this:

```
$p = '/\d{10}/';
preg_match_all($p, $x, $matchestel);
print_r($matchestel);
```